# NGINX - Rewrite .js.php file to .js

Tags: php, url-rewriting, nginx

I have a dynamically created file `start.js.php?c=21` and I would like to rewrite it's extension (to `start.js`, with query params).

1. Is that possible?
2. Is that a good method having such a rewrite?
3. Is wrong having query string `?c=21` on file location (to populate
   from PHP file with given `c` attribute)?

I am trying to create rewrite with:

```
server {
    location ~ \.js.php$ {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.js last;
    }
}
```

This is returning 404 error code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the underlying filename is `script.js.php` then it doesn't make sense to *rewrite* this to `script.js` - as that would result in a 404.

However, the directives you posted would seem to result in a 404 for a different reason, as they rewrite `script.js.php` to `script.js.php.js`.

Presumably, you want to link to `script.js?c=21` and internally *rewrite* this to `script.js.php?c=21` (the underlying file), thus hiding the `.php` file extension from users. In which case, try something like the following instead:

```
server {
    location ~ \.js$ {
        rewrite (.*) $1.php last;
    }
}
```

To answer your specific queries:

> 1. Is that possible?

Yes, but the "reverse" is probably what you really want to be doing. (?)

> 2. Is that a good method having such a rewrite?

It's OK. Presumably, you have a requirement to mix PHP and JavaScript?

> 3. Is wrong having query string `?c=21` on file location (to populate from PHP file with given `c` attribute)?

I don't think there is necessarily anything wrong with this. Bear in mind that some caching proxies may ignore the query string, but I think that is mostly historic.

Comment: You should use `rewrite...last` as the `.php` URI needs to be processed in a different `location`.